# How to get Bluetooth Address Of Sony Smart Watch

Tags: android, bluetooth, sony

I want to get Bluetooth address of Sony Smart Watch.

When any Android device connects to a Sony SmartWatch, it sends the Broadcast event `com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.registration.ACCESSORY_CONNECTION`.

On its Receive Intent there is no Extra data for Bluetooth device.

So I can't get the Bluetooth info on that Receive Method.

I can use Bluetooth Broadcast event `android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED` where i can get the Bluetooth info, but it will trigger on all the Bluetooth Connection & also overwrite the data when other devices are going to connect to my android device.

So my question is : Is there any way to get the Bluetooth Address or name of Sony SmartWatch. I have seen [Sony API References](http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/packages). But i cant find the way .

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can capture the Bluetooth address on the `ACL_CONNECTED` event, and then copy it on `ACCESSORY_CONNECTION`.  Or are you worried about race conditions for multiple simultaneous Bluetooth connections?

Comment: Same thing i have tried. But it is not working in race conditions.Its overwrite the address on `ACL_CONNECTED`  in multiple simultaneous Bluetooth Connections.